# Numerical solution to given equation involving one variable

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

Any neat way to solve this equation?

```
NSolve[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2, x]

NSolve[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2, x, 
 Method -> {"UseSlicingHyperplanes" -> False}]
```

Output says:  This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.

Comment: `FindInstance[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2 && x > 0, x, Reals, 1]`

Comment: `NSolve[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2, Reals]`

Answer (score 3):

```
 Plot[{(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x), 2}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you can try to help `NSolve` a little

```
 NSolve[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2 && 0 <= x , x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score -1):

```
NSolve[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2 && x > -10 && x <= 10, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> 1.}}`

```
FindInstance[(8^x-2^x)/(6^x-3^x)==2&&x>-10&&x<=10,x,Reals]
```

> `{{x -> 1}}`

Unfortunately,

```
FindInstance[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) == 2 && x > -10 &&   x <= 10, x, Reals, 2]
```

> `{{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}`

which is not correct.

Comment: Since `Limit[(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x), x -> 0]==Log[4]/Log[2]`, one can redefine `(8^x - 2^x)/(6^x - 3^x) `at `x==0` to make the result of FindInstance correct. –